gcc 11.4 openmp does not seem to generate AVX2 instructions. Based on this earlier stackoverflow, what am I doing wrong?
I am on popos using gcc 11.4
The commands I tried:
g++ -fopenmp-simd -O2 -S simd_reduction.cpp
g++ -fopenmp-simd -O2 -mavx2 -march=native -S simd_reduction.cpp

The code:
#include <omp.h>

float dot_product_simd(const float a[], const float b[], int n) {
    float dot = 0.0;
    #pragma omp parallel for simd reduction(+:dot)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        dot += a[i] * b[i];
    }
    return dot;
}

void multiply_arrays(const float a[], const float b[], float c[], int n) {
    #pragma omp parallel for simd safelen(8)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i] * b[i];
    }
}

The multiply_arrays does work with avx2 instructions given -fopenmp-simd.
The dot product reducing only uses xmm registers, so it is only doing 128 bit math.
Has this been fixed in later versions, is there something else I need to do?

What architecture is native on your machine?  -march=native implies -mtune=native which might have -mprefer-vector-width=128 for znver1 for example.  It auto-vectorizes with YMM in the inner loop (and XMM for the horizontal sums) with -march=skylake, or with -march=x86-64-v3 and the default tune=generic with GCC11 https://godbolt.org/z/3M9xPPxjG .  (Some earlier GCCs would have split maybe-unaligned loads and/or stores, but eventually they changed the default tuning to not do that.)

@PeterCordes this is a Ryzen7 7520U with 4 AVX512 AMD cores

According to https://www.amd.com/en/products/processors/laptop/ryzen/7000-series/amd-ryzen-5-7520u.html the 7520U is actually a Ryzen 5 not 7, based on Zen 2 cores.  (Surprisingly old for that model number, IDK if that's accurate.  edit: redditors say it sucks, that AMD's product numbering scheme is a scam for this CPU.)  GCC11.4 doesn't recognize -march=znver5 or znver4 (in which case tune=native might jut be tune=generic), but does recognize -march=znver3 and earlier, using YMM regs for that Zen 3 or Zen 2. https://godbolt.org/z/qvq633PEb

So anyway, try with -march=znver2 in case that's somehow different from -march=native, like if it doesn't recognize that your CPU is a Zen 2.  (Or if you actually do have AVX-512, then that's not your CPU model number and GCC11.4 is too old to recognize it for a tune setting for -march=native, but should still use AVX-512.)

Also note you're doing FP math, so none of the instructions GCC uses are actually AVX2, just AVX1.  AVX2 is 256-bit integer math, and some lane-crossing shuffles like vpermps.  But it only needs AVX1 vextractf128 for a horizontal sum, or actually the OpenMP vectorizer does inefficient horizontal sums, storing a vector to stack memory and looping scalar over the elements.

safelen(8) is certainly not needed here and the compiler should see that there is no dependencies here in this simple case. However, simdlen(8) is probably interesting here so to tell the compiler to use wider SIMD. That being said GCC 11 does not care about it :( .

Note -march=X make the program only work on X CPU architecture (and AFAIK generally more recent CPUs of the same group). If you plan to run this on your machine, this is fine, but if you plan to execute the program on another machine with another CPU, then this can result in a crash. In this case, it is better to just provide the supported instruction set and possibly use -mtune instead (using -march=X does not results in a huge speed up when instruction sets are provided anyway).

Oh and the provided functions are mainly memory-bound so AVX might not even be useful to get significantly better performance. Only few cores are certainly required to saturate the DRAM. I strongly advise you to merge functions so to avoid the program to be memory bound. Otherwise, it mostly waste your hardware resources. If you operate on in-cache data then using multiple threads can be detrimental for performance (very likely for the L1 cache, likely for the L2 -- Ok for L3 of your code is NUMA-aware).

@JérômeRichard: -march=x86-64-v3 is a good choice for enabling AVX2+FMA+BMI2 without any features that have come and gone or that are specific to one vendor.  Works on Haswell / Zen and later.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Microarchitecture_levels  But it doesn't imply a -mtune at all, unfortunately.  But fortunately these days tune=generic is appropriate for machines with AVX2 support.  Anyway, for running on your own machine, -march=native is the right choice, that's exactly what it's for.

With -fopenmp-simd, gcc probably only considers simd standalone directives, but ignore combined constructs. The compiler considers vectorization also without openmp directives, but will miss the safelen clause in that case. Can the function parameter overlap in your application? Marking the parameters with restrict might help for the optimizations.

@Joachim: https://godbolt.org/z/xf1Ms3nje shows GCC11.4 auto-vectorizing the OP's code with -Wall -fopenmp-simd -O2 -mavx2 -march=znver2 -fstack-protector-strong -fPIE which should be the same as -march=native on the OP's CPU.  I can't reproduce the OP's results with the upstream GCC of the version they're using. (Distros enable -fstack-protector-strong -fPIE by default, but those don't matter here.)

This is by design. Floating point addition is not associative, changing the order in which you sum values will change the output. By default, compilers don’t do optimizations which change output numbers, which means they won’t do any vectorizations for dot product function. Pretty sure your SSE instructions are doing scalar math, not vector math; scalar FP32 instructions end with ss, vector FP32 instructions with ps.
Try the -ffast-math compiler switch.

#pragma omp simd reduction(+:dot) with -fopenmp-simd allows the compiler to pretend that addition into dot inside that loop is associative, allowing GCC11.4 to auto-vectorize without -ffast-math.  https://godbolt.org/z/qvq633PEb shows an example with -Wall -fopenmp-simd -O2 -march=znver2.  Also, the second function is pure vertical SIMD, the only worry being __restrict if GCC doesn't want to do loop multiversioning and make a prologue that checks for overlap.  I can't explain what the OP's seeing, unless something in the default Debian config hurts vectorization.

(Oh, I see they're saying the second loop does use YMM regs for them.  But if the first doesn't, I agree it's probably not vectorized at all.)
